# mockmvc post request without csrf or invalid csrf is not failing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, spring-test, mockmvc

I have a *spring boot-2.5.1* application with *spring security 5*.

WebSecurityConfig looks as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomProperties customProperties;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (customProperties.isEnabled()) {
            log.info("authentication enabled.");
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                    .baseUri(customProperties.getAuthorizationResponseUri())
                    .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userService(new CustomOAuth2UserService()::loadUser));
        } else {
            log.info("authentication disabled.");
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/info", "/actuator/health/*");
    }
}
}
```

Controller looks like as below:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public @ResponseBody Mono<Map<String, String>> saveUsers(@RequestBody List<UserDto> userDtos) {
        return userService.saveUser(userDtos);
    }
}
```

JUnit corresponding to the above controller:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private  UserService userService;
    
        @SneakyThrows
        @Test
        @WithMockTestUser
        void shouldSaveUsers() {
            var userDtos = "...";
    
            mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(userDtos))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
    }
```

Above *JUnit* without *CSRF* is giving status as OK instead of forbidden request.
If I debug, I could see, if *csrf()* is not included then no token will be generated & assigned to request. However, still, the request is passing. Ideally, it should throw forbidden request access.

Even with *csrf()*, I can see token is generated & assigned to parameter.

In both cases, I do not see anywhere POST request is being validated whether it contains *CSRF* token or not with *mockmvc*.

**Does *mockmvc* need any extra configuration to validate whether *POST* request contains *CSRF* or not?**

Answer (score 0):

Rather than auto-configuring `MockMvc`, you need to build `MockMvc` using [`SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-setup).
This adds the Spring Bean named "springSecurityFilterChain" as a Filter and ensures that the `TestSecurityContextHolder` is leveraged for each request.

```java
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(this.context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I tried the suggested approach. However, still CsrfFilter is not called if csrf is added or not.However, I can see CsrfConfigurer still being called even if csrf is added or not. Hence, still the post request is success instead of forbidden access

Comment: @user2800089 What does `WithMockTestUser` look like? Do you get the same result if you use the built-in `@WithMockUser`?

Comment: @ WithMockTestUser is annotation having security context WithMockTestUserSecurityContextFactory. I have customized this because identity provider do not return principal information as default oauth2 user, hence i have customized userinfo and that's why customized mock userinfo